# select next record date minus 1 based on the logic

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I want to achieve the following output through sql query 
Below is the data in the oracle table

```
 date 1     date 2       amt1   amt2
1/1/2012    12/31/2012    100   100
1/1/2013    11/31/2013    100   100
1/1/2014    9/31/2014     50    100
1/1/2015    12/31/2015    20    100
```

### **Desired output I need:**

```
date 1    date 2       amt1    amt2
1/1/2012    12/31/2013    100   100
1/1/2014    12/31/2014    50    100
1/1/2015    12/31/9999    20    100
```

The logic to get the output would be if the amounts are same for multiple records then  a single record should exist in the output with the earliest date as date1 . date 2 of the record written to the output should be next record effective date minus 1 , and if there is no next record found ,the date 2 should be defaulted to 31-dec-9999

(Note:whenever there is a change in amt1 or amt 2 between 2 records, those should be treated as separate records and if amts are same for all records then a single record should exist in the output )

Please let me know how to achieve this output through sql query

Comment: Can you show us what you attempted that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a sub-query to aggregate a single row for each permutation of AMT1 and AMt2.  Then it applies an analytic LEAD() function to get the next DATE1 and manipulates it according to the specification.

```
with yt as (
    select amt1
           , amt2
           , min(date1) as date1
           , max(date2) as date2
    from your_table
    group by amt1
           , amt2
    )
select yt.date1
       , nvl(lead(yt.date1) over (order by yt.date1)-1, date '9999-12-31') as date2
       , amt1
       , amt2
from yt
order by yt.date1
/
```

By the way I had to correct your data (bad dates) when I used it in the inevitable SQL Fiddle; [find it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfa04/1).